# How to give Index Alias in Domain class instead of index name in Spring-dat-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

My current project requires to have a elasticsearch index that will be rolled over monthly.Index name will be like `Indexname-%{+YYYY.MM}`.

Now the problem is I am using Spring data elasticsearch to have the communication with elastic search and perform the crud operations.Currently For this in my domain class I have annotated as like below,

```
@Document(indexName = "indexname-2018.08", type = "Node")
public class Node {
......}
```

Currently i am giving the static index name.
My question is how can I use Alias of an index instead of direct index name,for eg something like below,

```
@Document(indexName = "indexname-current”, type = "Node")
```

where indexname-current is my alias name for all the index of type `Indexname-%{+YYYY.MM}`.

I am really stuck here. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spring data supports using Spring expressions [SPEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) in the index name

You can create a bean containing your rollover strategy.

```
@Component("rollover")
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class RolloverStrategy {

    private String monthlyDateFormat;

    @PostConstruct
    void after(){
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        monthlyDateFormat = formatter.format(date);
    }

    public String getMonthlyDateFormat() {
        return monthlyDateFormat;
    }

    public void setMonthlyDateFormat(String monthlyDateFormat) {
        this.monthlyDateFormat = monthlyDateFormat;
    }
}
```

Then reference this using SPEL in your class

```
@Document(indexName = "indexname-#{rollover.monthlyDateFormat}", type = "Node")
public class Node {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SPEL won't use the **rollover API** which IMO would be better. You have few other options:

1. Use the rollover API with the Java client/spring-data-es (just make a daily routine who creates a rollover request - read more: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-rollover-index.html)
2. Create an alias - same as you did in your example, let the rollover API call be made by a script, for example PUT request to server:9200/index/_rollover with .json:

   ```
   {
   "conditions": {
           "max_age": "1d",
           "max_docs" : 1000000
       }
   }
   ```

and run daily using cron job or by application (https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-time-based-indices-efficiently).

While using

```
@Document(indexName=yourAlias==Indexname, type=yourType)
```

spring-data-es will persist new documents to the existing active index using the alias you have created, this means any new document will be saved to the active index, which will be the newest one created by your previous rollover API call.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with Index Lifecycle Management (ILM) which is available in Elasticsearch 7. You can have Elastic automate the rollover for you, and just reference the alias for the Spring Data Elastic code. I annotated my entity with:

```
@Document(indexName = "myAlias", createIndex = false)
```

Then I added some code to invoke the ILM API at startup to ensure everything is setup and created:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticIndexConfiguration {

    private RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient;

    public ElasticIndexConfiguration(RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient) {
        this.elasticsearchClient = elasticsearchClient;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        // See ILM tutorial to:
        //   Create/update a lifecycle policy
        //   Create/update an index template that applies the lifecycle policy
        //   Bootstrap the initial time-series index / create the alias
    }
}
```

I referenced the ILM tutorial, and the Java API for the high-level REST client:

- [Tutorial: Automate rollover with ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html)
- [Index Lifecycle Management APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_index_lifecycle_management_apis.html)